# Can configuration code in Colab be sent to an object expecting a file?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, configuration-files

I'm using Python3 in Colab in an application extending neat-python. Large configuration files are required. I would like them to be in the Colab notebook for easy modifying but the Config object in neat-python expects a path/file. I could write a config file from the notebook and send it, but that seems very clunky. Is there any way to somehow package part of the notebook and make it look ike a file?

The relevant code from the neat-python Config object is:

```
class Config(object):
    """A simple container for user-configurable parameters of NEAT."""

    __params = [ConfigParameter('pop_size', int),
                ConfigParameter('fitness_criterion', str),
                ConfigParameter('fitness_threshold', float),
                ConfigParameter('reset_on_extinction', bool),
                ConfigParameter('no_fitness_termination', bool, False)]

    def __init__(self, genome_type, reproduction_type, species_set_type, stagnation_type, filename):
        # Check that the provided types have the required methods.
        assert hasattr(genome_type, 'parse_config')
        assert hasattr(reproduction_type, 'parse_config')
        assert hasattr(species_set_type, 'parse_config')
        assert hasattr(stagnation_type, 'parse_config')

        self.genome_type = genome_type
        self.reproduction_type = reproduction_type
        self.species_set_type = species_set_type
        self.stagnation_type = stagnation_type

        if not os.path.isfile(filename):
            raise Exception('No such config file: ' + os.path.abspath(filename))

        parameters = ConfigParser()
        with open(filename) as f:
            if hasattr(parameters, 'read_file'):
                parameters.read_file(f)
            else:
                parameters.readfp(f)
```

Comment: do you means standard module `io.BytesIO` and `io.StringIO` which create file object in memory? [documentation for io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

Comment: That looks very challenging. I’m just thinking that I have all of the configuration file information, organization, syntax, etc. in the notebook. It just isn’t in a file and of course has no path. Perhaps there is some kind of Python structure I could put it into that could then be passed as a file argument.

Comment: Turns out there's a pretty easy workaround. I have the config info in a cell. I write the cell to a file in My Drive using %%writefile. Then just give that file name in the call.